# request Spotify's /api/token got errors

Tags: javascript, api, http, authentication, spotify

According to the **Client Credentials Flow** part of Spotiy's [web api authorization guide](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/), I made the following request:

```
POST https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token
grant_type=client_credentials
Authorization: Basic Base64.encode(CLIENT_ID + ':' + CLIENT_SECRET)
```

and

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

But get the error:

```
415 Unsupported Media Type

{
    "error": "server_error",
    "error_description": "Unexpected status: 415"
}
```

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25432678/415-error-when-querying-spotify-for-tokens) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33249660/415-code-using-httr-and-rcurl-but-not-just-curl) SO questions, I changed the

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

However, I got `400 Bad Request`.

Anyone has other possible solutions?